# How to unpack the slice of string and pass them to exec.Command

Tags: go

I'd like to write a function that puts two slices of strings as arguments in a shell command. What I'm trying to do is to unpack the 2 slices, and pass them to `exec.Command`.

```
image_tag := "mydocker/mytag"
func buildDockerContainer(dockerArgs []string, otherArgs []string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("docker", "run", "-d", dockerArgs..., image_tag, otherArgs...)
}
```

However, when writing this, Goland keeps giving me syntax error:

```
Invalid use of '...', the corresponding parameter is non-variadic
```

I know I can do the following:

```
    cmdToRun := []string{"run", "-d"}
    cmdToRun = append(cmdToRun, append(append(dockerArgs, image_tag), otherArgs...)...)
    cmd := exec.Command("docker", cmdToRun...)
```

But is there a more elegant way that I can do all these inline?

Comment: You can provide a slice to a variadic function, or you can provide a comma separated list of values, but you can't provide a comma separated list of values *and* a slice.  So you have to make a slice that appends those values all together.  Since the same is true of append() itself, the answer is no - there's no  more concise way to append those values together.

Answer (score 3):

Use `append`:

```
args:= append(append(append([]string{"run","-d"},dockerArgs...),image_tag),otherArgs...)
cmd := exec.Command("docker", args...)
```

Comment: It gave same error: `Invalid use of '...', the corresponding parameter is non-variadic` over the first `append`.

Comment: It turns out that it gave the same error even when I do `cmd := exec.Command("docker", "run", "-d", dockerArgs...)`

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: if the first argument is string then, you can not send another type ([]string later, it should be consistent as append function for example)

Answer (score 0):

exec.Command(name string, arg ...string) behave same as append function in this case. the problem is that if the first arg is string, later it expect only string, but if you pass instead only slice that is fine.
https://go.dev/play/p/TBi3nsKue5n
and don't forget the ... at the end of a slice, when the function expect a string and you pass []string